# How to use the 'where' method from 'ActiveRecord::QueryMethods' in order to limit searching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, limit

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to limit a search in a `where` method from `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` using something as the following

```
Users.where(:name => "Test_name", :limit => 10)
Users.where(:name => "Test_name").limit(10)
```

That is, *I would like to query only 10 records*. How I can do that?

---

In the RoR source code there is:

```
def where(opts, *rest)
  relation = clone
  relation.where_values += build_where(opts, rest) unless opts.blank?
  relation
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second example works:

```
Users.where(:name => "Test_name").limit(10)
```

There is a nice list and explanation of all the query methods in this Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: If I use 'Users.where(:name => "Test_name").limit(10)' the search will stop when are found 10 records in the database or it will fetch all database and then will return the first 10 records?

Comment: It should only fetch 10 records. Calling the `limit(10)` method basically just adds a "LIMIT 10" clause to your SQL query (it doesn't even execute your SQL query yet, until you use a collection method like `first` or `each`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in where. You can only do

```
Users.where(:name => "Test_name").limit(10)
```

or if you insist to use :limit in other selector method:

```
Users.find(:all, :conditions => ["name = 'Test_name'"], :limit => 10)
```